Why is there no type-error when assigning a conditional return-type of string to a number?
I want to define a typescript function with a conditional return-type that depends on the type of the argument: Called with an argument of type true it returns a string and called with an argument of type false it returns a number. I came up with the following function foo() which almost works as expected:

calling it with true the correct return-type (string) is inferred
calling it with false the correct return-type (number) is inferred

But when directly assigning the function call to an incompatible type, no type error is thrown, why is that?
// generic function with conditional return-type TReturn that depends on TSomeArg
const foo = <
  TSomeArg extends boolean,
  TReturn = TSomeArg extends true ? string : number,
>(
  someArg: TSomeArg,
): TReturn => {
  // to return the conditional type TReturn, one needs to explictly assert it, since typescript will otherwise infer the union type: 'Some String'|1234
  return (someArg ? "Some String" : 1234) as unknown as TReturn;
};

// this works fine
const testOne = foo(true); // inferred string as expected: "const testOne: string"
//      ^?

const testTwo = foo(false); // inferred number as expected: "const testTwo: number"
//      ^?

const testThree: number = testOne; // throws Error as expected: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'."
const testFour: string = testTwo; // throws Error as expected: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'."

// BUT, here I would expect some type-errors
const testFive: number = foo(true); // unexpected: no type-error (string is inccorrectly accepted as a number)
const testSix: string = foo(false); // unexpected: no type-error (number is incorrectly accepted as a string)

// only when I explicitly define TSomeArg, then the type-errors are thrown as expected
const testSeven: number = foo<true>(true); // throws type-error as expected: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'."
const testEighth: string = foo<false>(false); // throws type-error as expected: "Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'."


same code at ts-playground

You should be using function overloads here, not generics. Right now it "works" (in that, it's unexpectedly correct) because you have a generic type parameter. Therefore, the caller can supply a generic type argument. Therefore, the caller could use foo<true, number>() - it's allowed by the function signature. If you don't want to allow this, then it shouldn't be something the caller is responsible for. And as always "I'll use generic to describe the different sets of function signatures I expect" is the wrong tool for the job here. Overloading does that.

Your function is generic in TReturn for no obvious reason; furthermore, you've only given it a default type argument (using =); it's not constrained (using extends). So the caller can set anything they want for TReturn.  I would suggest removing TReturn entirely as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@VLAZ I think you are right that generics are the wrong language feature to use here. Indeed, the caller should not be able to define a signature like foo<true, number>() which would contradict the actual implementation. I therefore tried using "function overloading" instead - as you recommend- and it works fine: https://tsplay.dev/NrY5Dw
But regarding the original code, my question remains: Why does the ts-compiler doesn't throw a type-error for const testFive: number = foo(true); - while const testOne = foo(true); is inferring a type of string?

@jcalz You're right. The caller should not be able to define the return type, the return type should solely depend on the type of the argument. I now think that "function overloading" as recommended by VLAZ is the best way to do it. However your approach (removing TReturn and asserting any) also fixes my original issue, since testFive and testSix throw the expected errors.  But regarding the original code, my question remains: Why does the ts-compiler doesn't throw a type-error for const testFive: number = foo(true); - while const testOne = foo(true); is inferring a type of string?

At the risk of repeating myself: you have only given TReturn a default type argument using =. It is not constrained using extends, as shown in this playground link. Defaults don't take precedence over inference, and TS infers that you want a number there because testFive is of type number. Does that clear it up now? Or is there still confusion?

@jcalz Well, I knew that I didn't define any constraint for TReturn but only provided a default type. But I wrongly assumed that when calling foo without explicitly defining the generic types (e.g. foo(true) instead of foo<true, string>(true)) that this would already force TReturn to fallback on its default.  I didn't understand that typescript could use the number type on the left side of the assignment const testFive: number = foo(true) to infer TReturn. I thought that this number type definition only affects testFive. But using NoInfer I now see your point: https://tsplay.dev/w8doVw

Ok, so it seems that my main problem was, not properly understanding the typescript concept of "contextual typing", which allows type inference, going from the left side of an assignment to the right side. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing

As written there doesn't seem to be any reason why foo is generic in TReturn, since the best case scenario is that TReturn is specified as TSomeArg extends true ? string : number, and any other type argument will give you behavior you don't want.  But the question here isn't about avoiding the bad behavior, but to understand why it's happening.

The main cause is that function return types serve as inference targets, as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#16072.  When you write
const testFive: number = foo(true);

you are calling foo(true) in a context whereby the return type is expected to be number.  And this serves as an inference site for TReturn.  Generic type argument defaults are only used if inference fails when you call the function.  But inference succeeds, and so the above call is  equivalent to
const testFive: number = foo<true, number>(true);

and you get the behavior you don't like.
